# How to load qt linguist dynamically changed label text

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

In my project i'm trying to  use qt linguist. When i change the  language from English to Turkish,  it is working all constant  label.

But some labels i m loading them  dynamically according to scenario of  use cases.

Whatever i do with  qt linguist, it doest workthe texts of these label.

How can i  get rid of this problem?

Any help will be apprecialted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has a [guide to internationalization](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/i18n-source-translation.html), which includes the basic information: to wrap your string in a `tr` function call.

```
label->setText( tr( "Hello, World!" ) );
```

In addition to this, if you want the language to change on the fly, you'll need to identify when the context has changed, and update your labels appropriately.  Unfortunately, I can't easily put my hands on the signal that indicates when to do so.